# How to tell which one of my plugins are paid or free?

Tags: plugins

I'm new to working on a specific WordPress site that has over 50 plugins installed.  Is there a technical thing I can do in WordPress or in a code editor like Visual Studio Code (i.e. search something?), to determine which of the 50 are free, or which of the 50 are premium plugins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually premium plugins that came with the purchase of a theme are updated via an external updater, not the wordpress built-in one. That could be one of the clues.

One obvious clue would be that the plugin has some kind of login/licence key system.

But when it comes to taking a look in the code, I'm afraid it's not an option cause the paid features can be implemented differently on every plugin.

Comment: Yeah I was hoping there was something that all premium plugins have that was required by WordPress, which we could searched for in the directory of plugin files.  But if such a rule does not exist, then I guess I'm out of luck :)